# forgot password, log in, but account now different?

Tags: support, merge-accounts

I haven't used stack overflow for a few years, but I had some rep on my old account.

So i click on 'forget password' a reset link gets sent to my email, I click it, and it logs me in, I ask a question, and I realise I'm no some kind of newbie user with no rep?

Where did my account go? :(

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/02/when-is-an-account-abandoned/

Comment: Did your account fall into the criteria mentioned in the above blog post?

Comment: hmm, yes, but I'm pretty sure I had a login/password. which is why i clicked on 'forgot password' and I assume it wouldn't have accepted my email address if it didn't exist in the database?

Comment: Well, one of the rules of security is that you don't tell people that - attackers can try lots of email addresses and if you tell them which ones are not in the DB, they can figure out which ones are...